# Practical consequences of breaking strict aliasing between int and float

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I once had a very subtle bug in one of the projects I had to maintain. Essentially it was doing something like this:

```
union Value {
    int64_t int64;
    int32_t int32[2];
    int16_t shorts[4];
    int8_t chars[8];
    float floats[2];
    double float64;
};

Value v;
// in one place (not sure about exact code, it could be just memcpy):
v.shorts[0] = <some short value>;
v.shorts[1] = <some other short value>;
// in another place:
float f = v.floats[0];
```

Now, as far as the standard is concerned, this is simply UB. In practice, this could mean anything, but I can hardly imagine a reasonable implementation that would cause the code above to start World War III or disintegrate my PC. In real life, I can only imagine two things happening:

1. The compiler may screw up something with optimizations, not realizing that it deals with the same memory here. Pretty unlikely in this case, since writes and reads happened in totally different places.
2. Nothing bad really happens, and the `float` value is simply read bit-by-bit.

In practice, it was *almost* always case 2, except for once. After running the program compiled with MSVC 2010 in release mode on about 100-150 input files, in one of the files it generated an incorrect value that differed in exactly one bit from what it was supposed to be according to the common sense. That was a pretty significant bit, too, so instead of, say, `1.5`, I got something like `117.9`. I was able to trace it down to that exact read, and after fixing the code to adhere to strict aliasing rules, everything worked fine.

Now the question is, purely from low-level point of view, what could have caused that? Some peculiarities in CPU handling floating-point values? Hardware caching specifics? Compiler quirks? Why only one value was wrong?

The hardware was some old 2-core 64-bit Intel CPU running a 32-bit Windows 7, if that is of any help. The program is a single-threaded console application, nothing fancy. The problem was 100% reproducible, the same input files always produced the same output, and it's always the same value that was wrong.

Comment: You'd really need to look at the assembly output; reasoning about UB at the language level is madness, reasoning about it at the assembly level is merely silly ;)

Comment: @TartanLlama, that was a while ago, I no longer have the exact code and inputs, so I don't think I can reproduce it. I was looking more for theoretic knowledge from low-level software and hardware experts. Not what *caused* that, but what *could* have caused that.

Comment: I guess that a compiler which was doing a lot of alias analysis might notice that the `floats` part of the union has never been initialized, so the object is not alive, and therefore just give you something uninitialized. LLVM has `undef` for marking this in the IR, for example.

Comment: @TartanLlama, what is the probability of reading an uninitialized value that differs from the correct value in only one bit? 2^-31 or so? Unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the Standard, the code `v.shorts[0] = something;` takes a pointer value of type "short*", adds zero, and uses the resulting pointer to store a value.  I think the authors of C89 intended that quality implementations where aliasing would be useful would recognize aliasing in this case, but nothing in the letter of the Standard would require it.  Note that when the rules were included in C89, compilers were only expected to apply them on a very local level; further, the rules generally don't pose severe problems for programmers unless they're applied at a more far-reaching level.  Unfortunately, some compilers are aggressively seek to extend the range of the rules as far as possible.

If you were to place each array within a separate structure within the union and then do something like:

```
v.floats.arr[0] = value;
v.floats.arr[1] = value;
v.floats = v.floats; // Compiler knows that float* may alter float members,
                     // and that writing member of union may alter other
                     // members
```

... now use other stuff

a compiler should hopefully recognize that the assignment to v.floats need
not generate any code but a conforming compiler must must still regard it as proper notice that other members of the union may have been altered.  Note that the pattern does not seem to be reliable in gcc as of 6.2, however; in some cases when an assignment is not required to generate any code, the compiler will ignore the assignment--including its aliasing implications--altogether.  I don't see any reason to bend over backward working around gcc's broken behavior, however--simply use -fno-strict-aliasing guilt-free unless or until gcc's aliasing logic gets fixed.

Comment: Interesting information, but doesn't quite answer my question. I understand a lot of things could possibly happen. What I don't understand is what kind of thing could happen that would cause a 1-bit error in one particular value. And it worked fine with GCC, only MSVS 2010 in release mode produced that curious effect.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: Optimizations are weird.  It would be helpful to know what values had been written to everything overlapping the `float` around the time of the errant read, what value was expected, and what value was received.  Sometimes optimizations can shift writes around as well as reads, so it's possible that some value which is written after read in logical execution order might occur earlier in the machine code if the compiler doesn't think the order will adversely affect things.  I wouldn't expect MSVC2010 to do that, but something is behaving in unexpected fashion.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: In any case, whether or not gcc is misbehaving presently, I do think it's important to know that the authors of gcc have openly stated that the fact that a piece of code works a certain way on today's gcc does not constitute any sort of promise that tomorrow's version won't break it if the code relies upon any behaviors beyond those mandated by [the authors' interpretation of] the Standard.